# Regular expression - finding specific string with at least one capital letter

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression which matches a specific string which:

1. always  start with  `"fu:`
2. always ends with `"`
3. and contains at least one capital letter in between those start and ending points

point 3 is the part I really can't solve.

the regex `"fu:(.*)?"` matches all the strings apart from point 3.

[edit]
its pretty close now, the only problem is it doesnt stop after the second ".
Basically this string:
"fu:no capital letter:,some other random text WITH CAPITAL LETTERS"
is a match but shouldnt.

Comment: `[A-Z]` will match a capital case letter.

Answer (score 3):

The regex that will work for you is this:

```
/^"fu:.*?[A-Z].*?"$/
```

Here the [live demo of above regex](http://www.rubular.com/r/cBUaBLVsrC)

Comment: this is a match but shouldnt:"fu:any text but n capital letter",but there is a Capital letter which I dont care about"

Comment: The problem with this is that it only matches capital letters in the range A through Z. For example, the Ruby code `['"fu:Berlin"', '"fu:İstanbul"', '"fu:Washington"', '"fu:Örebro"', '"fu:Москва"'].map {|s| s.scan /^"fu:.*?[A-Z].*?"$/}` returns `[["\"fu:Berlin\""], [], ["\"fu:Washington\""], [], []]`, although all of the strings theoretically contain capital letters.

Comment: Also, could you please give an example of a string that `/^"fu:.*?[A-Z].*?"$/` could match, but `/^"fu:.*[A-Z].*"$/` couldn't? Thanks!

Comment: @goTAN: `"fu:any text but n capital letter"` doesn't match as you can see here: http://www.rubular.com/r/Q07Zkl3vRB Also would like to know in what language/platform are you implementing this regex? Do you need to support upper case letters of other languages than English also?

Answer (score 1):

```
^"fu:.*[A-Z].*"$
```

Don't forget about multiline mode if you wish to search in several lines of text.

```
^"fu:  - starts with "fu:
.*     - any other characters
[A-Z]  - capital letter
.*     - other characters
"$     - " at the end
```

Good tool to test it: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: Why not? "contains at least one capital letter" -> [A-Z]+ or I'm mistakeen? :)

Comment: Ok, understood. + is unnecessary :) Thanks!

Comment: hm using anchors doesnt work apparently... I am trying to perform a regex search with sublime text 2.
this regex: "fu:.*[A-Z].*" is perfect except it doesnt stop after the second "
the following string shouldnt be a match:
"fu:any text but no capital letter", here is one capital letter S

Comment: I don't see any capital S here... And it doesn't match according to my tests.

Comment: shouldn't be a match:
"fu:any text but no capital letter",but THERE is one"

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
^"fu:([^"]*?[A-Z][^"]*?)"$
```

Comment: yea thats pretty close. it just doesnt stop after the end"

Comment: Updated to use the ^ and $ line delimiters

Comment: I dont know why but the ^ and $ line delimiters doesnt work in the sublime text2 search.

Comment: They should do, according to the documentation.  Try escaping the " (I've updated my answer to match)

Comment: anubhava has got it, both of the .* need the ? to not be greedy

Comment: no, sorry apparently I am not clear.the following string should NOT be a match:
"fu:there is no capital letter", but Heree is"

Comment: New suggestion, using [^"] to indicate anythign that's not the closing "

Comment: If that's working for you, feel free to accept the answer for your solution

Answer (score 0):

I commented on a problem with anubhava's solution (that it only matches upper case letters in the range A through Z), but then found the solution myself. Note that this requires a [POSIX-compliant regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions) engine with support for Unicode.

My solution is

```rb
/^"fu:.*[[:upper:]].*"$/
```

It solves the problem of finding upper case letters in other languages than English (with partially or completely different alphabets).

An example in Ruby:

```rb
rx = /^"fu:.*[[:upper:]].*"$/
arr = ['"fu:Berlin"', '"fu:İstanbul"', '"fu:Washington"', '"fu:Örebro"', '"fu:Москва"']
arr.map {|s| s.scan rx}
```

In this case, all of the strings are matched.